# Always display header file above implementation file in Visual Studio in tab group

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Apologies if this is a dup, had a look but couldn't find anything surprisingly.  I just wondered when creating a a new class in visual studio (2013 or 15 or whatever really) that it creates a horizontal tab group with the header file on the top and implementation file below.  I know it creates both files and opens them and opens them.  After this I can do it manually but just wanted to save myself a couple of clicks really.  If it's not in VS options is there a macro out there or something?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I don't currently think this is possible but have put a feature request in for 2015

Comment: Well the only feature in VS that creates .h and .cpp files for you is "Add ->class"

Comment: @jafar - thanks for getting back to me.  I know, this exactly the feature I was talking about, I've edited the question to reflect that.  I know it opens the files for you I just wondered if there was anyway of it opening them in a horizontal tab group